# Can you help a newbie out

Tags: vpython, glowscript

The position of an aerial imaging drone can be described by the following expression:
r(t) = (3 m) cos((0.6π r/s)t) ı̂+ (2 m) sin((0.6π r/s)t) ȷ̂+ (0.05 m/s^2)t^2k.
Note the arguments of the trigonometric functions are in radians.

GlowScript Simulations:
i. Use GlowScript to simulate the motion of the drone. You may use a simple box
or sphere object as the drone. Be sure to include a ground/floor so that the
motion of the drone is clearly visible.
ii. Using your GlowScript simulation, calculate the position, velocity, and
accelerate of the drone at tt = 10 ss. What value of dddd is appropriate for these
calculations?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is "dddd"?